# Form input not sending?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have this form

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'groups', 'role' => 'form','files' => true ,'data-toggle' => 'validator']) !!}
 <input type="file" id="group-picture" name="avatar" class="modern-uplaod-input"/>
 <input type="text" name="team_name" class="form-control"/>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Create</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

When i try to upload the image, and the request file array is

```
avatar = {
 test => false,
 originalName => 587756.jpg,
 mimeType => application/octet-stream,
 size => 0,
 error => 3,
 *SplFileInfo*pathName => "",
 *SplFileInfo*fileName => ""
}
```

and the `team_name` input didn't send to the server.
any ideas?

Comment: Show us the method in your controller and where you dump this data. Maybe it is because you file has some errors?

Comment: Check your server's php.ini and htaccess upload_max_filesize and post_max_size. If file is bigger you'll get an error like the one reported.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is:

UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL
Valor: 3; file is partially uploaded.

Try looking into this:

## .htaccess

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
```

Method for phpSuExec Create a local php.ini in the document root directory

## php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize=100M
post_max_size=105M
max_execution_time=600
max_input_time=600
```

Create or add to the current .htaccess file the location of the php.ini file